# What does the notation "$\not\preceq$" mean for graph databases?

Tags: graph-theory, research

I'am reading a research paper about graph databases and i stumbled upon a notation that i don't understand .. I was far from academia for a while so help is much appreciated ..

[image]

The highlighted part is the one i don't understand ..
Also how can i easily lookup these symbols and notations without the need to refer back to somebody ..

Thank You

Comment: The diagonal line through the symbol simply means "not."  Think about $\neq$.

Comment: Ohh. Snap .. I missed that ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A less than equals but with the curly lines is used frequently for to show the definiteness of a matrix. Though I don't think that works in this context. Judging from the context of the paper it seems like the symbol is being used for the representation of a binary relation in a partially ordered set.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set

---

Whenever I don't know a symbol, I use this classifier:

http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

It gives the answers in terms of LaTeX but that's typically enough for a good starting point.